# Updating 1 group through MailChimp API v2.0 while multiple is created

Tags: php, mailchimp

I have list which consists of multiple groups, with batchSubscribe I want to update only single group in list, is that possible or every update should contain information about other groups also?

replace_interest must be set to true (default)

this is my code for batchSubscribe:

```
foreach ($company->users as $user) {
                if ($this->isValidAdmin($user)) {

                    $subscribers[] = ['email' => ['email'           => "$user->email"],
                                                  'email_type'      => 'html',
                                                  'merge_vars'      => ['fname'       => $user->first_name,
                                                                        'lname'       => $user->last_name,
                                                                        'mc_language' => $user->lang,
                                                                        'groupings'   => [
                                                                            ['id'     => Config::get('mailchimp.companies.status'),
                                                                             'groups' => [$company->status]]]]
                    ];
                }

    $subResult = $this->mailchimp->lists->batchSubscribe($adminList, $subscribers, false, true);
```

Or it is not possible, and I need to include info about all groups with all API requests I make?

Answer (score 0):

In v2, you will need to provide all group data, there's no way to do partial updates. In v3 of the API this is possible, though.